# Is it safe to use my Flickr API key in client-side JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, security, flickr

I want to use the Flickr API method **flickr.photos.search** in JavaScript, to search for all my photos with a specific tag:

```
http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key={API_KEY}&user_id=50001188%40N00&tags=fazynet&format=rest
```

(To make it work, change `{API_KEY}` to a valid Flickr API key.)

My question is: **Is it safe to include that key in client-side JavaScript?**

I've seen some tutorial sites doing it, but what's to stop someone copying their API key (or mine) and going over the rate limits?

Of course, I could set up a very simple proxy running in Node.js that inserts the key (probably even Apache or Nginx could do it), but it's one more thing to set up and monitor.

If there's a safe, pure JavaScript solution, I'll take that please. :)

Note, I am currently using this query which requires no authentication:

```
http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?id=50001188@N00&tags=fazynet&format=json
```

However, the results appear to be no longer reflecting changes (after at least a 24-hour wait).

Comment: There's no way around it. If you use it in client-side code, it becomes visible to end users, and they can copy it to their own scripts. The best you can do is obfuscate your Javascript to make it harder for them to get at it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to protect an API Key when using JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11470389/710446)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a pure JavaScript method to achieve this I'm afraid, you will have to create a server-side script to perform the API call and call that script instead.

Comment: Sure, I haven't managed to think of any way it could be done with the current Flickr API (maybe they could change it to only allow requests from certain domains, but not even sure that's possible).

Comment: Unfortunately not, as the request would be coming from the users browser, so they wouldn't know (or confirm) which domain it had come from. Plus there isn't really any need for this. But good question.