# validating JS API calls

Tags: javascript, php, api, rest

Im building API for my customers which sends data on their requests

customers will be integrating it via javascript, they are given a public key and a private key, they make calls with these and I authorize their account and process data to their account with this.

problem is, since customers are using JS, others can see whats passing and can get to know the public and private keys of that customer and can attempt spam info via API.

I added a validation from the referrer domain, so lets say my customer purchases my product to use on domain-a.com, I validate every request and serve only if it comes from domain-a.com but I came to know that it is possible in CURL to change referrer, so any hacker from domain-b.com can make call to API by masking the referrer, so they actually make calls from domain-b.com but send referrer as domain-a.com, this is the case where my system fails to recognize authentic users.

any ideas on solving these kind of problems?

Comment: Isn't the whole point of encryption is that you need to have both keys (meaning access to both source and destination PC) to decrypt the data? At any rate, you could looking into a way to compile those keys into a webapp or implement some advanced security procedure, like public keys being stored in a database and only accessible by logged on customers (so the keys are not in code and you can actually change them easier).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11470389/how-to-protect-an-api-key-when-using-javascript

Comment: @Zero if they use on same domain, or if they use my API via iframe then I can save the public key in sessions and compare it with private key i database with every call, but they use it with their domain and no sessions work there

Comment: @JohnnyFaldo from your ref, building a PHP wraper for client is secured, but as long as it stays with clients, if they share to others, logic is out they can build it again