# Vulnerability Level of jQuery/AJAX API call in webpage

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, api, security

I have a simple call to a REST API using jQuery/AJAX. I realize that the parsing method here could be done more elegantly and will ask another question on that(although any comments here are welcome).

Current Question: Are there glaring or not-so-glaring vulnerabilities in using this method to retrieve and parse api data. Would using a server-side script to retrieve it first behind the firewall and save it outside the firewall to access it through this webpage be a marked improvement?

```
$(function() {


$.ajax({

    type: "GET",
    async: "true",
    crossDomain: "true",
    url: "https://data.usajobs.gov/api/Search?Organization=XXXX&WhoMayApply=All",
    headers: {
        "authorization-key": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "user-agent": "XXXX@XXX.gov",
        "host": "data.usajobs.gov",
        "cache-control": "no-cache",
    }
}).done(function(data) {
    "use strict";
    var jts = [];
    var json_obj1 = (data.SearchResult.SearchResultItems);
    var json_obj2 = $.makeArray(json_obj1)


    $.map(json_obj2, function(v) {

        var start = v.MatchedObjectDescriptor.PositionStartDate;
        var start_f = moment.utc(start).format('MMMM Do YYYY');

        var end = v.MatchedObjectDescriptor.PositionEndDate;
        var end_f = moment.utc(end).format('MMMM Do YYYY');



        jts.push("<tr><td><strong><a href='" + v.MatchedObjectDescriptor.PositionURI + "'>" + v.MatchedObjectDescriptor.PositionID + ", " + v.MatchedObjectDescriptor.PositionTitle + "</a> &#187</strong></td><td>" + v.MatchedObjectDescriptor.JobGrade[0].Code + "-" + v.MatchedObjectDescriptor.UserArea.Details.LowGrade + " - " + v.MatchedObjectDescriptor.UserArea.Details.HighGrade + "</td><td>" + start_f + " - " + end_f + "</td><td>" + v.MatchedObjectDescriptor.UserArea.Details.WhoMayApply.Name + "</td></tr>");

        //show table on success()
        $('.job_table').css('display', 'block')
        $('#no_message').css('display', 'none')
    });

    var ls = jts.join("")

    $('.job_table tbody#live_jobs').html(ls);

    console.log(ls)


  });

});
```

Comment: So you're wanting to hide the authorization key?  What exactly are your goals?  If you're wanting to hide the auth key, then yes, you need to write a web service that accepts the AJAX request, gets the data from usajobs.gov, and then returns that data.

Comment: Just hiding the auth key for this post, it would have a valid auth key and user-agent value,  sorry not to clarify that.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11470389/how-to-protect-an-api-key-when-using-javascript.  You basically just need to do it server side.

Comment: I do not necessarily need to hide the auth key, I just hid it for this SO post, just as I did my email. I want to know about any security issues with this in-page method of using jQuery/Ajax that returns json to make an API call.

Comment: I think you'll need to ask pointed questions--the only security issue I see is that someone can easily get your auth key and email address.  If you aren't worried about someone else getting those, then I don't know what your concerns are. Since this question has gone 23 hours with no answers, it seems that other readers are not sure of what the question is either, because there are a lot of SO readers that LOVES to opine about security, even when the question isn't about security issues.

Comment: "there are a lot of SO readers that LOVES to opine about security, even when the question isn't about security"... is exactly why I posted my code and a general question, opening the discussion up to any and all input on the security of the code.  Thanks for pointing out that if my auth key and email address are in the code, that someone can easily get it.