# How to determine if my Python Requests call to API returns no data

Tags: python, json

I have a query to an job board API using Python Requests. It then writes to a table, that is included in a web page. Sometimes the request will return no data(if there are no open jobs). If so, I want to write a string to the included file instead of the table. What is the best way to identify a response of no data? Is it as simple as: if response = "", or something along those lines?
Here is my Python code making the API request:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import requests
import json
from datetime import datetime
import dateutil.parser
url = "https://data.usajobs.gov/api/Search"

querystring = {"Organization":"LF00","WhoMayApply":"All"}

headers = {
   'authorization-key': "ZQbNd1iLrQ+rPN3Rj2Q9gDy2Qpi/3haXSXGuHbP1SRk=",
    'user-agent': "jcarroll@fec.gov",
    'host': "data.usajobs.gov",
    'cache-control': "no-cache",
    }

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)


responses=response.json()



with open('/Users/jcarroll/work/infoweb_branch4/rep_infoweb/trunk/fec_jobs.html', 'w') as jobtable:

    jobtable.write("Content-Type: text/html\n\n")
    table_head="""<table class="job_table" style="border:#000">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <th>Vacancy</th>
    <th>Grade</th>
    <th>Open Period</th>        
    <th>Who May Apply</th>
    </tr>"""
    jobtable.write(table_head)
    for i in responses['SearchResult']['SearchResultItems']:
        start_date = dateutil.parser.parse(i['MatchedObjectDescriptor']['PositionStartDate'])
        end_date = dateutil.parser.parse(i['MatchedObjectDescriptor']['PositionEndDate'])
        jobtable.write("<tr><td><strong><a href='" + i['MatchedObjectDescriptor']['PositionURI'] + "'>" + i['MatchedObjectDescriptor']['PositionID'] + ", " + i['MatchedObjectDescriptor']['PositionTitle'] + "</a></strong></td><td>" + i['MatchedObjectDescriptor']['JobGrade'][0]['Code'] + "-" + i['MatchedObjectDescriptor']['UserArea']['Details']['LowGrade']+ " - " + i['MatchedObjectDescriptor']['UserArea']['Details']['HighGrade'] + "</td><td>" + start_date.strftime('%b %d, %Y')+ " - " + end_date.strftime('%b %d, %Y')+ "</td><td>" + i['MatchedObjectDescriptor']['UserArea']['Details']['WhoMayApply']['Name'] + "</td></tr>")

jobtable.write("</tbody></table>")

jobtable.close
```

Comment: Does it return an empty JSON object `{}` or nothing at all?

Comment: it returns an Empty JSON object

Comment: I hope those credentials you posted, are not sensitive ;)

Comment: schwobaseggl: Last  time I posted it with the credentials X'ed out, I went down a rabbit hole of comments about how to hide my credentials: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37392954/vulnerability-level-of-jquery-ajax-api-call-in-webpage

Comment: Good read :D I see. I just tried your code and saw that they were valid credentials to obtain a proper response. Maybe you just tweak 'em a little without X-ing them out.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You have a couple of options depending on what the response actually is. I assume, case 3 applies best:

```
# 1. Test if response body contains sth.
if response.text:  # body as str
    # ...
# body = response.content:  # body as bytes, useful for binary data

# 2. Handle error if deserialization fails (because of no text or bad format)
try:
    json_data = response.json()
    # ...
except ValueError:
    # no JSON returned

# 3. check that .json() did NOT return an empty dict/list
if json_data:
    # ...

# 4. safeguard against malformed/unexpected data structure
try:
    data_point = json_data[some_key][some_index][...][...]
except (KeyError, IndexError, TypeError):
    # data does not have the inner structure you expect

# 5. check if data_point is actually something useful (truthy in this example)
if data_point:
    # ...
else:
    # data_point is falsy ([], {}, None, 0, '', ...)
```

Comment: SOLVED: So this works...
if responses['SearchResult']['SearchResultItems']: Thanks!

Comment: @JohnnyP you should check first whether there is SearchResult key in responses

Comment: `responses.get('SearchResult', {}).get('SearchResultItems')`

Answer (score 2):

If your APIs has been written with correct status codes, then

1. 200 means successful response with a body
2. 204 means successful response without body.

In python you can check your requirement as simply as the following

```
if 204 == response.status_code :
    # do something awesome
```