# how to fix python request error "Expecting value"

Tags: python, python-requests

i'm trying to get the json response of couple of product ids page. I used this

[Python : how to set parameters for python request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63993790/python-how-to-set-parameters-for-python-request)

to succesfully query a word response but I don't know why query by product id is not working. I started with with this

this is actual url to the product

https://www.walmart.com/ip/Breyers-CarbSmart-Frozen-Dairy-Dessert-Chocolate-48-oz/10898747

so I started with this code

```
prodID = '10898747'


url = 'https://www.walmart.com/ip/'

params = {
    
    'product_id': prodID,

}

data = requests.get(url, params=params).json()
print(data)
```

but it's produces this error

> Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

what am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?

Comment: check what response you get. obviously it's not valid json

Comment: Check the `status_code` of the response first.

Comment: @buran please i updated the question with the actual ur

Comment: and it does not return json, as expected

Answer (score 1):

The url is not returning a valid json object.

Going there in my browser yields a 404: https://www.walmart.com/ip/?product_id=743876032

And running it from a fiddle, it returns some sort of forbidden string https://repl.it/repls/BossyHoneydewMicrostation

In other words, the problem is not in your code but the request is not working.

To prevent such errors, check the response: [How to determine if my Python Requests call to API returns no data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37605278/how-to-determine-if-my-python-requests-call-to-api-returns-no-data/37605377)

```py
try:
    response = response.json
except ValueError:
    ...
```

Comment: The link you posted is to a html page. You are looking for a json response. You can use the walmart product lookup API: https://developer.walmartlabs.com/docs although it seems they are not allowing more registrations so you might be out of luck.

Comment: yes I posted the html link for you to see and check if I am using the right call method/url