# How to use API Keys in a website (ie Cognitive services) without disclosing keys?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

API Keys in web side context are never secured, this can be a big problem if API services are paid for. How to solve this problem in Azure Cognitive Service context ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are referring to not exposing the keys to the end user who is browsing to your website, as opposed to securing the keys on the webserver itself from another admin on the server.

This isn't really a Cognitive Services question, but a question generic to any secrets you want to keep when hosting a website (or creating a mobile app, or really any app that uses some sort of key or password).

The short answer is, don't give the key to the client, which means that the client can't directly make the call to Cognitive Services, and you have to have code running on your web server that makes the call.

Generally you would do one of two things:

1. Code running on your web server would make the call to Cognitive and then process and display relevant results to the user via the webpage.
2. Your web server would expose an API, and then you would have client side script call your API.  Your API internally would call the Cognitive Services API and return the data where the client side script would process and display the results.

You can also find similar info at [How to protect an API Key when using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11470389/how-to-protect-an-api-key-when-using-javascript), or a web search for something like 'web development protecting api keys javascript'.

Comment: Yes it is, but in the context of cognitive services, a web socket is opened on client side with API key, using an intermediate server implies providing sufficient server ressources to assume the load, as where as in case of direct connection from webclient to Azure, the load is only one time assumed by azure.

Comment: Yes, that is the tradeoff if you need to protect your key.