# How to access Bing Images Search API in javascript on client side without exposing credentials?

Tags: image, api, search, bing, bing-api

Is there a way, I can access Images API from the browser, without actually exposing my API Keys and credentials ? This question applies to any API. How can we expose an API to javascript client side browsers, without exposing secrets ?

Answer (score 0):

It's discussed here: [How to protect an API Key when using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11470389/how-to-protect-an-api-key-when-using-javascript).

Short answer, make calls from server side as much as possible. In that case, you can whitelist your client through domain/IP/login, etc. From client side alone, you can make it difficult but not impossible for somebody willing to steal your keys.

You can also regenerate keys time-to-time just to be safe and keep track of your usage just to be sure.